# Enable WYSIWYG for a custom textarea form field in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, wysiwyg

i have created a custom form in my custom drupal6 module and the form has a textarea.
I am outputting the form as html embedded inside the php code, like the following:

```
function custom_my_form() 
{
$f = '<form name="add_user" action="" method="post">
<label>  Name </label>
<p><input type="text" name="name" value="" /></p>
<label>About Yourself</label>
<p><textarea name="desc"></textarea></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>';

return $f;
}
```

I have installed and enabled the WYSIWYG module. 
My default input format is "Filtered HTML" and i have chosen the FCK editor for this input format.

Now i want to enable the WYSIWYG for the textarea field in this form. 
How can i go ahead with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not create forms like that. Instead, use Drupal's built-in Forms API.  Take a look at the [Form API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826) for more information.

This page on Drupal's site will help you add WYSIWYG to your custom forms: http://drupal.org/node/358316

Comment: But i have chosen the html way of creating forms for one of my modules, instead of using the built-in drupal's form api. Is there no way i can enable wysiwyg for my textarea?

Comment: You could probably manually add the JavaScript library to the page.  `chosen the html way of creating forms for one of my modules`: Using the forms api still outputs HTML and can be styled to your liking. Everything in your code above can be done with Drupal's api

Answer (score 9):

Well, how ever you create forms is up to you, it just depends if it has ever come back to bite you in the butt...

Look at the comment module. I had noticed that it was possible to choose input format for comments, and when Full/filtered HTML was selected, the WYSIWYG editor kicked in. Here is the related code:

```
$form['comment_filter']['comment'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Comment'),
  '#rows' => 15,
  '#default_value' => $default,
  '#required' => TRUE,    

);
if (!isset($edit['format'])) {
  $edit['format'] = FILTER_FORMAT_DEFAULT;
}
$form['comment_filter']['format'] = filter_form($edit['format']);
```

So, you define an array with two elements, one of which is the textarea itself, and the other one the format chooser generated by filter_form, and that's all.

This was from http://groups.drupal.org/node/104604

Answer (score 9):

For D7, its even simple. We got new type called text_format.

```
$form['comment'] = array('#type' => 'text_format', 
                         '#format' => 'full_html', 
                         '#title' => t('Description'), 
                         '#required' => TRUE);
```

Comment: Does anything else is needed for this, it did not seem to work

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. Just add the following javascript to your page.

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

This script automatically converts the text areas in your html code to rich text editors

More info at this [link](http://www.tinymce.com/).